# Loading up first time server for Rails 3, and received this error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization, ruby-on-rails-3

```
Started GET "/users/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2010-07-11 23:07:03 -0400
Processing by UsersController#new as HTML
Completed   in 15ms

I18n::UnknownFileType (can not load translations from /Users/johnsmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/gems/activesupport-3.0.0.beta4/lib/active_support/locale/en.yml, the file type yml is not known):
```

I check out the file path to see what was there, and en.yml is there. Opened it up, and it all looks legit out of the box. I havn't moved anything anywhere. Not entirely sure why I'm getting this.

Here's my gemfile :

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.0.0.beta4'

gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'
gem "hpricot"
gem "ruby_parser"
gem "rack",          "1.1.0"
gem "rack-mount",    :git => "git://github.com/rails/rack-mount.git"
gem "rack-test",     "~> 0.5.0"
gem "erubis",        "~> 2.6.0"
gem "arel",          :git => "git://github.com/rails/arel.git"
gem "sqlite3-ruby"
#gem 'bj' #not entire sure what a bj is, but this version is wrong and kills the system
gem "rails3-generators", :group => :development 
gem 'nokogiri', '1.4.1'
gem 'aws-s3', :require => 'aws/s3'
gem 'authlogic'
gem 'i18n'

group :test do
  gem "test-unit",  "1.2.3"
  gem "rspec", :git => 'git://github.com/rspec/rspec.git'
  gem "rspec-rails", :git => 'git://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails.git'
  gem "factory_girl"
end


gem 'capistrano'
```

Also this is Ruby 1.9.3dev

Rails 3.0.0.beta4

**Edit:**

I added that i18n gem only after I received this error thinking that would resolve it, but its still the same error with or without it.

Comment: i assume you did a bundle install on these gems?

Comment: Yes sir. At this point, I'll take literally any setup I can get to at least get the most primitive basic rails3 app up and running. Haha, nothing works :(  . What's you're gemfile look like? I'll just copy that!

Comment: then i dunno what the issue is. you might try loading with ruby 1.8.7p249 and see if it is a ruby 1.9 issue. 1.9 isnt required for rails 3 and y katz (rails core team) says that he doesn't think it is a stable option yet.

Comment: Will definately revert to that. 1.9 is like trying to ride an old dying donkey.

Comment: at least you can try the 1.9.2rc instead of 1.9.3dev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Went ahead and installed Ruby 1.8.7 and Rails 3.0.0.beta4 , and everything works perfectly.

Thanks Jed!